# How to count how many times an object property has changed

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm creating a unit test to check how many times `window.location.hash` has changed.

```
it("checking location.hash change", () => {
  myLink.click();
  // expecting window.location.hash is changed only one time.
});
```

How can I spy on an object property in [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)?

Comment: I would tell you to monkey patch the attribute or function, but I don't think that's an option since `window.location.hash` is probably read only.

Comment: For testing stuff like this (e.g., anything off `window` I generally wrap it in a module/class, that way I can just stub/mock/etc. it and remove the need to play games.

Comment: Really, whatever is setting `location.hash` should be setting some wrapper that can be mocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `window.onhashchange` event, to increase a counter on each change... Would that work for you?

```
var changes = 0;
window.onhashchange = x=> changes++;
```

For other objects/properties, you could use the same  principle,  using GETTERS or PROXIES. 
Another alternative could be using some library that allows you yo watch variables. One option could be [WatchJS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/)

Comment: Upvoted but ideally, the OP would allow the hash object to be mocked.